# Deserializing an object in one line for an interface attribute?

Tags: java, class, serialization, interface, attributes

I was wondering if there is some way to deserialize an object and assign it to an attribute in an interface?

I have tried the code below, but I don't know how to check for a "FileNotFound" exception with it, and of course I can't just type `throws FileNotFoundException`.

```
public interface Race_Attributes {
    String[] FirstNames = (String[]) new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("./res/binary_files/Human_FirstNameString[].ser")).readObject();
}
```

Comment: You could check for an exception with a try / catch block, but you can't just put code in an interface. Code can only go inside of methods, and normally interfaces contain only abstract methods although starting in Java 8 they can contain default methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the issue of checked exceptions when initializing implicitly static interface attributes by wrapping the initialization code in a helper method.

```
public interface Race_Attributes {
    String[] FirstNames = Deserializer.deserializeFirstNames();
 }

final class Deserializer {

    private Deserializer() {}

    public static String[] deserializeFirstNames() {
        try(ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(
                "./res/binary_files/Human_FirstNameString[].ser"))) {
            return (String[]) in.readObject();
        }
        catch( IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            return new String[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Because Java 8 allows static methods in interfaces, you could also place your helper method `deserializeFirstNames` directly in the interface. However, because methods in interfaces have to be `public`, this would would negatively impact the information hiding quality of your interface, so in the example I've placed it in a separate utility class.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your willingness to answer a question this old.